# How do I upgrade amazon linux to python 3.10?

Tags: amazon-linux

Made an ec2 with amazon linux, has python 3.9 installed.  What command do I run to upgrade it to python 3.10?  Not 3.11, I need 3.10.  I am building a lambda layer